# WPF DataGrid.GroupStyle with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I try to list several data items which should be visualized in three different groups:

- Dashboard
- Housekeeping
- Science

Working with the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) design pattern, I made two Model classes:

**DataGroup.cs**

```
public class DataGroup
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

**DataItem.cs**

```
public class DataItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Format { get; set; }
    public DataGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

...one ViewModel class:
**DataListViewModel.cs**

```
class DataListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<Models.DataGroup> GroupList { get; set; }
    public List<Models.DataItem> DataList { get; set; }

    public DataListViewModel()
    {
        var GroupList = new List<Models.DataGroup>
        {
            new Models.DataGroup
            {
                Name = "Dashboard"
            },
            new Models.DataGroup
            {
                Name = "Housekeeping"
            },
            new Models.DataGroup
            {
                Name = "Science"
            }
        };

        var DataList = new List<Models.DataItem>
        {
            new Models.DataItem
            {
                Name = "Panel A",
                Format = "N/A",
                Group = GroupList[0],
            },
            new Models.DataItem
            {
                Name = "Panel B",
                Format = "N/A",
                Group = GroupList[0],
            },
            new Models.DataItem
            {
                Name = "Panel C",
                Format = "N/A",
                Group = GroupList[0],
            },
            new Models.DataItem
            {
                Name = "+3.4 V",
                Format = "TBD",
                Group = GroupList[1],
            },
            new Models.DataItem
            {
                Name = "+5.3 V",
                Format = "TBD",
                Group = GroupList[1],
```

`etc.`

Here the XAML code **DataList.xaml**

```
<ListView Name="PersonListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <!-- DataList -->
    <DataGrid BorderBrush="Black"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
                <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush4}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>

        <!--GroupStyle to group data-->
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>

                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupList, IsAsync=True}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                <!--Group DataItems into DataGroup-->
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}">
                                        <Expander.Header >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" - " Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format" Binding="{Binding Format}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnRightAlignStyle}"/>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="SID" Binding="{Binding Sid}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnRightAlignStyle}"/>-->

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I was able to visualize the DataList, but gouping them did not work. How do I have to change my code in the DataListViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

To group a list like that, you need to use CollectionViewSource.

Add it to your resources somewhere like so:

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedDataList" Source="{Binding DataList}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

And bind to that instead of directly to the `DataList`:

```
    <DataGrid BorderBrush="Black"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedDataList}}"
```

The `GroupStyle` display is also a little off - you don't need the `HeaderTemplate` in there with the `ContainerStyle` that you've applied. In addition, you'll want to change the `Binding` of the first `TextBlock` there to `Name.Name`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name.Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" - " Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Foreground="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But you can play around with the bindings and placements and work out what suits you best.

Oh, and the last thing I did was to remove the ListView at the top, it was completely covered up in the sample app that I made. Depending on your containing XAML, that might not be the case for you though.

Hope this helps!